# Loop with break

Tags: powershell

```
Foreach ($dir in @("C:","D:","E:","H:","I:"))
{
    IF (Test-Path $dir\folder\Office_task.bat)
    {
       Copy-Item $dir\folder\Office_task.bat C:\Users -Force
       break
    }
    IF (Test-Path $dir\folder\xml\Office.xml)
    {
        Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content "$dir\folder\xml\Office.xml" | Out-String) -TaskName "Office" -Force
        break
    }
}
```

How to first loop through all drives and copy a file from the first it is found, and then loop through all drives again and register a task.
Currently my file is only being copied. May be because of an incorrect `break` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resolve-Path` can help here:

The first two checks find the correct path, then if more then one path found it use the first one, then execute your task for that path

```
$Drives = @("C:","D:","E:","H:","I:")

$OfficePath = ($Drives | % {Resolve-Path $_\folder\Office_task.bat -EA SilentlyContinue}).Path
$XmlPath = ($Drives | % {Resolve-Path $_\folder\xml\Office.xml -EA SilentlyContinue}).Path

$OfficePath = $OfficePath | select -First 1
$XmlPath = $XmlPath | select -First 1

if ($OfficePath) {Copy-Item $OfficePath C:\Users -Force}
if ($XmlPath) {Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content $XmlPath | Out-String) -TaskName "Office" -Force}
```

Comment: This maybe cause a problem if `\folder\Office_task.bat` is located on multiple drives and he only wants to copy it from the first drive.

Comment: If I don't use break command Register-ScheduledTask try to register two identical tasks one by one, because .xml file is in two different folders.

Comment: My goal is to loop through all drives and copy the first found file in the loop and then register task with first found xml file.

Comment: Yes, I used that variant, but how to use Foreach (...) only once?

Comment: Isn't your variant too complicated for my task?

Comment: I think is the short one, try to understand the logic

Comment: No, it doesnt copy the first found file from C:\. It copies from the D:\ drive.

Comment: Yes, now works fine, but I still think the code is too monstrous for my task. :)